# Implement a program in Matlab for LU decomposition with pivoting

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-science, math-software, matlab

I need to write a program to solve matrix equations Ax=b where A is an nxn matrix, and b is a vector with n entries using LU decomposition. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use any prewritten codes in Matlab. I am having problems with the first part of my code where i decompose the matrix in to an upper and lower matrix.

I have written the following code, and cannot work out why it is giving me all zeros on the diagonal in my lower matrix. Any improvements would be greatly appreciated.

```
function[L R]=LR2(A)

%Decomposition of Matrix AA: A = L R

z=size(A,1);

L=zeros(z,z);

R=zeros(z,z);

for i=1:z

% Finding L

for k=1:i-1

L(i,k)=A(i,k);

for j=1:k-1

L(i,k)= L(i,k)-L(i,j)*R(j,k);

end

L(i,k) = L(i,k)/R(k,k);

end

% Finding R

for k=i:z

R(i,k) = A(i,k);

for j=1:i-1

R(i,k)= R(i,k)-L(i,j)*R(j,k);

end

end

end

R

L

end
```

I know that i could simply assign all diagonal components of L to be 1, but would like to understand what the problem is with my program!

I am also wondering how to change this program to include pivoting. I understand I need to say that if a diagonal element is equal to zero something needs to be changed. How would I go about this? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have assigned $L$ to be a zero matrix and the for loop for $i^{th}$ row of $L$ runs from the first column to the $(i-1)^{th}$ column. The entry $L(i,i)$ is still left unchanged. So the diagonal entries still remain zero.

Comment: @Sivaram so would it be "cheating" to simply assign all of my L(i,i)s to be 1? Thanks alot :)

Comment: No it wouldn't. The best way is to decompose $L$ and $U$ directly in $A$. Since you know there will be ones on the diagonal, for huge matrix dimensions saving the previous known zeros and ones is a waste of memory space.

Answer (score 1):

For backward and forward elimination I used

> ```
> % Now use a vector y to solve 'Ly=b' 
>  for j=1:z
>
>     for k=1:j-1
>        b(j)=b(j)-L(j,k)*b(k);
>     end;
>     b(j) =b(j)/L(j,j); 
>  end;
>
> % Now we use this y to solve Rx = y
> ```
>
> x = zeros( z, 1 );
>
> ```
> for i=z:-1:1    
>  x(i) = ( b(i) - R(i, :)*x )/R(i, i); 
> end
> ```

I put that into your code, and it works ;)
For helping you with pivot strategies it would be helpful to know what strategie you want/have to use as there are various versions. One simple version would be to just swap rows such that the diagonal element $a_{ii} \neq 0$ for all $i = 1, \dots, z$.

Answer (score 0):

> function[L R x]=LR2(A,b)
>
> % This program will find a solution to
>   Ax=b using first giving the
>   decomposition of the matrix into L and
>   R and then solving.
>
> % Part 1 - Is this matrix square and
>   nonsingular? give an error if not
>
> [z y]=size(A);
>
> if (z ~= y )
>
> disp ( 'LR2 error: Matrix must be
>   square' );
>
> return;
>
> end;
>
> if det(A)==0
>
> ```
> disp('L singular error');
>
> return;
> ```
>
> end
>
> % Part 2 : Decomposition of matrix
>   into L and R
>
> L=zeros(z,z);
>
> R=zeros(z,z);
>
> for i=1:z
>
> % Finding L
>
> for k=1:i-1
>
> L(i,k)=A(i,k);
>
> for j=1:k-1
>
> L(i,k)= L(i,k)-L(i,j)*R(j,k);
>
> end
>
> L(i,k) = L(i,k)/R(k,k);
>
> end
>
> % Finding R
>
> for k=i:z
>
> R(i,k) = A(i,k);
>
> for j=1:i-1
>
> R(i,k)= R(i,k)-L(i,j)*R(j,k);
>
> end
>
> end
>
> end
>
> for i=1:z
>
> ```
> L(i,i)=1;
> ```
>
> end
>
> % Program shows R and L
>
> R
>
> L
>
> % Now use a vector y to solve 'Ly=b'
>
> y=zeros(z,1);
>
> y(1)=b(1)/L(1,1);
>
> for i=2:z
>
> ```
> y(i)=-L(i,1)*y(1);
>
> for k=2:i-1
>
>     y(i)=y(i)-L(i,k)*y(k);
>
>     y(i)=(b(i)+y(i))/L(i,i);
>
> end;
> ```
>
> end;
>
> % Now we use this y to solve Rx = y
>
> x=zeros(z,1);
>
> x(1)=y(1)/R(1,1);
>
> for i=2:z
>
> ```
> x(i)=-R(i,1)*x(1);
>
> for k=i:z
>
>     x(i)=x(i)-R(i,k)*x(k);
>
>     x(i)=(y(i)+x(i))/R(i,i);
>
> end;
>
>  end
> ```
>
> %print x 
>   x 
>   end

I have solved the original question. However there are still some problems with my solving of Ly=b and Rx=y. I also need to include pivoting. Any improvements would be greatly appreciated again!

Comment: It is easy to solve triangular systems by backward or forward substitutions. For pivoting you need some way to keep track of the permutations.

Answer (score 0):

After finding the L and U matrix, I tried to find the appropriate B matrix. After then, finding X is a little bit more easier than the traditional way.

```
% Modifying B
B_new = B;
for i = 2:n
   for k = 1:i-1
       B_new(i,1) = B_new(i,1) - B_new(k,1)*L(i,k); 
   end
end

% Finding X
x = zeros(n, 1);
i = n;
while(i>0)
   x(i) = B_new(i,1);
   k = n;
   while(k > i)
       x(i) = x(i) - x(k)*U(i,k);
       k = k - 1;
   end
   x(i) = x(i) / U(i,i);
   i = i - 1;
end

x
```

I hope it works for you :)
Greetings from Turkey

NOTE: n equals to z, B equals to b